# Realtime update for table

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of problem where the table is located in page1 and the second page (page2) is where I can update data in database, so the thing is I want the page1 automatically/realtime update without refreshing page1 when I change/update something in the page2. Don't have any idea in JavaScript how I can do that?

Comment: Do you mean where a user changes the info from Page 2 and other users already had Page 1 open you want to update the data displayed for those other users? Use polling at regular intervals, long-polling, or websockets.

Comment: Looks like you don't want your page 1 to poll the server for updates. This is typically what websocket was designed for. Have a look at socket.io for example.